# simple grep expressions

Tags: linux, grep, regular-expression

I have a few grep expressions that aren't working as I intended and I cannot figure out as to why.

The first expression is to find lines that start and end with the same character. This is the expression I am using...

```
grep -E '(.).*\1$' input
```

The second expression is very similar as it is to find lines that have the same 2nd character and second to last character...

```
grep -E '(.)(.).*\2.$' input
```

The last expression is to find lines with only a single word and end with a punctuation...

```
grep -E '(\w){1}.*[[:punct:]]$' input
```

I don't understand why these are not working, am i doing something terribly wrong or just a simple mistake?

Answer (score 4):

You left off the start-of-line [anchor](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) ([caret symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret)). Here are modified commands which only match entire lines (and won't match substrings):

```
grep -E '^(.).*\1$' input

grep -E '^(.)(.).*\2.$' input

grep -E '^(\w){1}.*[[:punct:]]$' input
```

You'll probably also want to modify your second and third commands.

The second command doesn't require two [capture groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). You can do it with just one:

```
grep -E '^.(.).*\1.$' input
```

The third command is incorrect: it will match strings with multiple words. A corrected version might be:

```
grep -E '^\w+[[:punct:]]$' input
```